# Swift Core Data two sort descriptors

Tags: core-data, swiftui

Any help would be great. Core Data is using "Date" for both due date and due time. Values are from Swift UI picker (displayedComponents: .date) and (displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute).  It doesn't sort correctly.

```
var fetchCategories = [Category]()
            let request: NSFetchRequest<Category> = Category.fetchRequest()
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isComplete == 0")
            let sortDueDate = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dueDate", ascending: true)
            let sortDueTime = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dueTime", ascending: false)
            let sortDescriptors = [sortDueDate, sortDueTime]
            request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
            request.predicate = predicate
            do {
                fetchCategories = try moc.fetch(request)
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching categories \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return fetchCategories
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Date` attribute in Core Data stores both date and time. I am guessing the `dueTime` attribute contains a date that is after the `dueDate` date, causing the sort issues.

The solution is to store the `dueDate` as just one attribute. This attribute contains both a date and a time, which you can modify separately in your user interface. You only need one `SortDescriptor`, too.